# Subversive (Eclipse SVN plugin) reports externals as obstructed

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

After doing a fresh checkout using Subversive, some of the directories retrieved because of svn:external properties are showing up as obstructed. However not all of them are. A command-line use of "svn status" properly shows all the directories as externals with no obstructions.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

This does looks like [this thread](http://forums.polarion.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=664)

> We checked the situation and we had found that the problem can happen in case if **working copy is locked by external process in time of update**.
>
> For example, the process TSVNCache that related to TortoiseSVN time-to-time produces conflicts with working copy access and JavaSVN library cannot complete working copy modification in correct way. As result working copy goes into "Obstructed" state, i.e. it is damaged.
>
> The same diagnosis related to any process which locks working copy in time of working copy meta-data modification. (We found same behavior for MS Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition, but I don't know why the Studio locks WC?)

So be sure to make the checkout with the least possible number of application running.

---

Another source of conflict could be:

> The SVN 1.4.x-compatible clients are automatically converts working copy into 1.4.x-compatible format. At the current moment Subversive Default client is incompatible with SVN 1.4.x working copy format.
>
> So, if you performed any modification of the working copy using command line SVN client in your case you will get "Obstructed" state indicated over the resources in the workspace tree.
>
> In order to resolve the problem I will propose you to switch SVN client option and select SVN Kit 1.1.0-based client or Native JavaHL 1.4.2 client.
> Next, if resources already decorated as "Obstructed", please close and then open again corresponding projects or simply restart Eclipse IDE in order to reload SVN meta-information cache.

Now : the exact version may not be the same for you, but that is another lead to check.